# React Native - If within List data loop render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of data which I am displaying in a list using `<List dataArray=`

Inside of this loop I want to do some conditional checks to determine whether to display something e.g.

```
<List dataArray={ this.state.appointments } renderRow={(data) =>
    <View>
        #Need to set a variable inside conditional so it only displays once if there are multiple on the same date.
        {data.start_actual == formatted_today ?
            <ListItem itemDivider style={{backgroundColor: 'crimson'}}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Today</Text>
            </ListItem> : null }          

          <ListItem>
            <Left style={{flex: 0.4}}>
              <Text>{data.name}</Text>
            </Left>
          </ListItem>
    </View>
</List>
```

The two values in my if are read as "text" rather than "variables", how do I change that? And how do I set a variable within the conditional statement so i can set it if it gets inside so it doesn't render it twice?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "text" rather than "variables". Do you mean that the values are string representations of dates that aren't equal, when the dates are actually the same?

Comment: hey did you find a solution yet ? i'm having a similar problem

Comment: @user3521011 I didn't, i did it a much more manual way in the end!

Comment: hey i faced a similar problem myself .. take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563724/render-a-scrollview-after-a-condition-in-react-native if you want